# identify observations based on 2 elements in 2 dataframes that do not match

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I want to identify observations in 1 df that do not match that of another df using 2 indicators (id and date). Below is sample df1 and df2.

```
df1
id       date          n
12-40   12/22/2018     3
11-08   10/02/2016     11
```

```
df2
id       date          interval
12-40   12/22/2018     3
11-08   10/02/2016     32
22-22   11/10/2015     11
```

I want a df that outputs rows that are in df2, but not in df1, like so. Note that row 3 (based on id and date) of df2 is not in df1.

```
df3
id       date          interval
22-22   11/10/2015     11
```

I tried doing this in tidyverse and was not able to get the code to work. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `anti_join` from `tidyverse` (as the OP mentioned about working with `tidyverse`).  Here we use both 'id' and 'date' as mentioned in the OP's post.  More complex joins can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df2, df1, by = c('id', 'date'))
#     id       date interval
#1 22-22 11/10/2015       11
```

---

Or a similar option with `data.table` and it should be very efficient

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[!df1, on = .(id, date)]
#      id       date interval
#1: 22-22 11/10/2015       11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("12-40", "11-08"), date = c("12/22/2018", 
"10/02/2016"), n = c(3L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c("12-40", "11-08", "22-22"), date = c("12/22/2018", 
"10/02/2016", "11/10/2015"), interval = c(3L, 32L, 11L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Both options are `base R`, follow OP directions and do not require any package):

```
#Code1
df3 <- df2[!paste(df2$id,df1$date) %in% paste(df1$id,df2$date),]
```

Output:

```
     id       date interval
3 22-22 11/10/2015       11
```

It can also be considered:

```
#Code 2
df3 <- subset(df2,!paste(id,date) %in% paste(df1$id,df1$date))
```

Output:

```
     id       date interval
3 22-22 11/10/2015       11
```

Some data used:

```
#Data1
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("12-40", "11-08"), date = c("12/22/2018", 
"10/02/2016"), n = c(3L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

#Data2
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("12-40", "11-08", "22-22"), date = c("12/22/2018", 
"10/02/2016", "11/10/2015"), interval = c(3L, 32L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `merge` + `subset` + `complete.cases`

```
df3 <- subset(
  u <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("id", "date"), all.y = TRUE),
  !complete.cases(u)
)[names(df2)]
```

which gives

```
> df3
     id       date interval
3 22-22 11/10/2015       11
```